# button e grid não passar por cima do menu

Tags: html, css, div

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]olá é a primeira vez que faço alguma questão ou que utilizo esta plataforma algo peço já desculpa.

Bem a questão aqui é como faço para isto não acontecer?

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: none;
}

header .menu {
    background-color: rgb(92, 101, 148);
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    
}

.menu {
    padding: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 130px;
}
.menu a {
    background-color: none;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.down {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: medium;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

.algo{
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0/*topo*/ 10px/*direita*/ 10px/*bottom*/ 10px/*esq*/;
}

.algo h3{
    text-align: center;
}
/*corpo*/
main{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.container{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;

}

.dropdown-item a{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.grid-container{
    padding: 10px;
}
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="menu">
            <img class="logo" src="../img/small_logo.png" alt="Logotipo">
            <a class="down"  href="#inicio" aria-label="#">Inicio</a>
            <a class="down"  href="#sobre" aria-label="#">Sobre</a>
            <a class="down"  href="#serviços" aria-label="#">Serviços</a>
            <a class="down"  href="#contatos" aria-label="#">Contatos</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="algo" id="inicio">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Algo</h3>
    </div>
    <main>
        <div class="algo" id="sobre">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h3>Algo</h3>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="container">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;">Videos</h3>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                  <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button"><a href="#podcast-ultimo"> Video 1 </a></button></li>
                  <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button"><a href="#podcast"> Video 2 </a></button></li>
                  <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button"><a href="#Video"> Video 3 ou + </a></button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 center">
                    <div id="podcast-ultimo" class="grid-container">
                        <div class="card">
                            <h3>Video 1</h3>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                            <pre>Some text</pre>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 center">
                    <div id="podcast" class="grid-container">
                        <div class="card">
                            <h3>Video 2</h3>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                            <pre>Some text</pre>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 center">
                    <div id="Video" class="grid-container">
                        <div class="card">
                            <h3>Video 3</h3>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                            <pre>Some text</pre>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 center">
                    <div id="Video" class="grid-container">
                        <div class="card">
                            <h3>Video 4</h3>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                            <pre>Some text</pre>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 center">
                    <div id="Video" class="grid-container">
                        <div class="card">
                            <h3>Video 5</h3>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                            <pre>Some text</pre>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 center">
                    <div id="Video" class="grid-container">
                        <div class="card">
                            <h3>Video 6</h3>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                            <pre>Some text</pre>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 center">
                    <div id="Video" class="grid-container">
                        <div class="card">
                            <h3>Video 7</h3>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                            <pre>Some text</pre>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 center">
                    <div id="Video" class="grid-container">
                        <div class="card">
                            <h3>Video 8</h3>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                            <pre>Some text</pre>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="algo" id="serviços">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h3>Algo</h3>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: aqui o seu código não está sobrepondo as divs, mas você poderia usar flex grid ou flexbox pra resolver seus problemas

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente é a propriedade position: fixed; que vc está dando tanto no header qto no menu. Isso provavelmente está causando esse provlema. Portanto vc tem que dar um margin-bottom no header ou um margin-top na div onde exibe os vídeos!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Agradeço Pedro Franca mas não deu em nada.. resumindo ele continua a flutuar por cima do menu.